# Can we update objects in all instances of Azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function that loads configuration at the start up as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). As per my understanding, the azure functions can run in multiple instances. Is there a way by which I can update the configuration in all those instances programmatically?

For now - I have I tried creating an HTTP Trigger function but I feel it will only update the object in the instance it is running.

Here is my code for HTTP Triggered azure function to update the config object.

```cs
  public class TestUpdater
    {
        private IServiceProvider provider;
        public TestUpdater(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }
         [FunctionName("Update")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "update")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (log is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
            }

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
           var obj = provider.GetService<MyConfig>();

           ++obj.counter;
           obj.message = obj.counter.ToString();


            return new OkObjectResult(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Each instance will anyway go through the startup for injection. Why do you want to manually do it ?

Comment: @HariHaran , I am not worried about startup when new instance starts. My worry is suppose there are 2 instances of Function App running and I want to tell all the functions to reload the configuration from an external source.

Comment: You could use KeyVault as a configuration provider and turn on auto refresh.

Comment: If your functions are taking that long to execute then you might want to refactor your systems architecture.  Functions should be as small as possible and shouldn't run for very long.

Answer (score 1):

Even when Function app is running on multiple instances, Azure Infrastructure will take care of replicating the code and configuration on all the instances . As a end User you don't need to worry about this .

For ex. When you scale out your Function app , Azure infrastructure will automatically replicate all your code base and configuration on all the instances. Customer does not need to worry about replicating code and configuration on each of the instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2ftoc.json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale